# Kickstarter type dictionary equivalent in spring boot graphql starter

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java, spring-graphql

When using `spring-boot-starter-graphql` Spring is using a simple name to class mapping. E.g. for a mutation:

```
mutation {
  addCategory(id: 6, name: "Green Fruits", products: [8, 2, 3]) {
    name
    products {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Spring will check for a mutation called addCategory and for a class named `Product`.

graphql-java-kickstart offers a way to maintain a dictionary for classes not matching that pattern:
https://www.graphql-java-kickstart.com/tools/schema-definition/#type-dictionary

Is there anything similar for `spring-boot-starter-graphql` ?

Spring's [TypeResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#execution-graphqlsource-runtimewiring-configurer) seem to to this for Interfaces and Unions

Answer (score 0):

There is no such dictionary, but you can override the default behavior and customize the type resolver.

Assuming you have this Graphql schema

```
type Product {
    sku: ID!
}

type Address {
    streetName: String
}

type Query {
    product(sku: ID!): Product
    addresses: [Address]
}
```

And you want to use a different class name for Product

```
class ThisIsTheProduct {
    private String SKU;
}
```

You can implement `RuntimeWiringConfigurer` for register the tpye and the name.

```
@Configuration
class GraphQlConfig implements RuntimeWiringConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void configure(RuntimeWiring.Builder builder) {
        ClassNameTypeResolver typeResolver = new ClassNameTypeResolver();
        typeResolver.addMapping(ThisIsTheProduct.class, "Product");
        builder.type(new TypeRuntimeWiring.Builder().typeName("Product").typeResolver(typeResolver).build());
    }
}
```

Your query in the controller in this example will be something like this:

```
@Controller
class ProductQuery {

    @QueryMapping
    public ThisIsTheProduct product(@Argument String sku) {
        return new ThisIsTheProduct(sku);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: TypeResolvers are working for Interfaces and Unions only:
GraphQlSource.Builder registers ClassNameTypeResolver as the default TypeResolver to use for GraphQL `Interfaces and Unions` that don’t already have such a registration through a RuntimeWiringConfigurer.

Comment: I updated the answer so you can see how to use a different class name for a type.